# Primefaces datatable cell editing new and old values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have a data table and i can not get the old and new value. i can only get the new value 
why?

code that works on ajax event

```
   <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{productMapBean.onEdit}"/>
```

backing bean:

```
    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws SQLException {

    System.out.println("BEGIN:: onEdit");
    if (ds == null)
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

    // get database connection
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {

        String myPreparedStatement = preparedStatements.getUpdateStmt();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(myPreparedStatement);

        ps.setString(1, ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getCode());
        ps.setString(2, ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getSubcode());
        ps.setString(3, ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getDestination());
        ps.setString(4, ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getMapped());
        ps.setString(5, mappingDataUpdate.getCode());
        ps.setString(6, mappingDataUpdate.getSubcode());
        ps.setString(7, mappingDataUpdate.getDestination());
        ps.setString(8, mappingDataUpdate.getMapped());

        int executeUpdate = ps.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("row updated: " + executeUpdate + " - " + ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getCode() + " - " + ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getSubcode()
                + " - " + ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getDestination() + " - " + ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getMapped());
        System.out.println("row updated: " + mappingDataUpdate.getCode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getSubcode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getDestination() + " - "
                + mappingDataUpdate.getMapped());
        System.out.println("key : " + mappingDataUpdate.getRowkey());
        System.out.println("key2 : " + ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getRowkey());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getLocalizedMessage()));
    } finally {
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    }
    dataList = null;
}
```

code that should get the old value:

```
   <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{productMapBean.onRowSelect}"/>
```

backing bean:

```
   public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("BEGIN:: onRowSelect");
    if(mappingDataUpdate==null){
        if (((MappingData) event.getObject()) != null) {
            mappingDataUpdate = ((MappingData) event.getObject());

            System.out.println("row: " + mappingDataUpdate.getCode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getSubcode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getDestination() + " - "
                    + mappingDataUpdate.getMapped());
        }
    }
}
```

the log say:

14:58:55,170 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) BEGIN:: onRowSelect

14:58:55,170 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) row: 1 - 1 - DTCC-DFA - q    <-- when i select the row

14:58:58,323 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) doFilter

14:58:58,340 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) BEGIN:: onEdit  <-- when i press the check mark on the cell editor

14:58:58,342 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) row updated: 1 - 1 - REGIS-TR - q  <-- are the same why?

14:58:58,342 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) row updated: 1 - 1 - REGIS-TR - q <-- are the same why?

14:58:58,343 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) key : 11REGIS-TRq

14:58:58,343 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) key2 : 11REGIS-TRq

14:58:58,359 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) doFilter

14:58:58,373 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) BEGIN:: onRowSelect  <-- This is called alone by jsf after check mark onEdit backing bean is called

14:58:58,386 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) doFilter

the question is Why the variable

```
  mappingDataUpdate
```

do not hold the value!!! and it is resetted to the new value???

row updated: 1 - 1 - REGIS-TR - q  <-- are the same why?

row updated: 1 - 1 - REGIS-TR - q <-- are the same why?

in the code 1 refer to

```
 mappingDataUpdate.getCode()
```

and another refer to

```
 ((MappingData) event.getObject()).getCode()
```

why are the same?

Comment: can you tell me if i m right?? the code works but i do not understand why there was a wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because mappingDataUpdate is serializable object

because doing :

```
   public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        if (((MappingData) event.getObject()) != null) {
            mappingDataUpdate = ((MappingData) event.getObject());
            this.destination = mappingDataUpdate.getDestination();
            this.mappedValue = mappingDataUpdate.getMapped();
            this.subProduct = mappingDataUpdate.getSubcode();
            this.product = mappingDataUpdate.getCode();
            System.out.println("row: " + mappingDataUpdate.getCode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getSubcode() + " - " + mappingDataUpdate.getDestination() + " - "
                    + mappingDataUpdate.getMapped());
        }

}
```

it works.

Comment: can you tell me if i m right?? the code works but i do not understand why there was a wrong.